# ANR when launching the Home screen from notification

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent, android-anr-dialog

I am pretty new and naive to the world of android development. I am working on an existing issue in our android app and so far I have had no luck fixing it. I apologize for asking a lengthy question.

In the current app which is meant to track whether a shopkeeper has his/her shop open or closed, we are displaying a notification on which user can click (when the app is not opened in the foreground) and set the flag from "Duty Off" to "Duty On". If the user has location services turned off and user tries to click on the notification from "Duty Off" to "Duty On", system tries to get Latitude and longitude of the user, makes a POST callout and opens the app home screen. When the app home screen opens, user is seeing an Application not responding error. This only happens in the case where the user has turned off their location.

Below is a snippet of my code which is the class invoked when this action occurs and it is majorly responsible for 2 methods createNotification and fun_DutyONOFF. After Googling a lot myself, it seems that if BroadcastReceiver does not complete within 10 seconds, Android will throw up the Application Not Responding (ANR). But I am not sure what is the alternative here and why does it go ANR if the location services are turned off? Any help would be life saving since I have spent 3 days on this with no luck.

```
public class SwitchButtonListenerON extends BroadcastReceiver {
//Class variable declaration that I have omitted
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ("dutyON".equalsIgnoreCase(intent.getAction())) {
            SharedPrefrence_Login.getDataLogin(context);
            location_update = new Location_Update(context);
            createNotification(context);
//This is probably the method "fun_DutyONOFF" that takes more time but I am not sure how to replace the work done by this method
            fun_DutyONOFF("1",SharedPrefrence_Login.getMhawker_code(),context);
        }
    }
private void createNotification(final Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "Hawker", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    }
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Home.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,notificationIntent,0);

    Intent dutyIntent = new Intent("action.cancel.notification");
    PendingIntent pendingDutyIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,dutyIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    RemoteViews notificationView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout);
    //the intent that is started when the notification is clicked (works)
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Location Service")
            .setContentText("")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_business)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .build();
    notification.contentView = notificationView;
    notification.contentIntent = pendingDutyIntent;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
    notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.closeDuty, pendingDutyIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1 , notification);
    }else {
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    }
}

private void fun_DutyONOFF(final String sStatus,final String hawker_code,final  Context context) {
    requestQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).getRequestQueue();
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Urls.URL_DUTY_ON_OFF_SELLER,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        // _progressDialog.dismiss();
                        // converting response to json object
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                        String str = obj.getString("data");
                        JSONObject jsoObject = new JSONObject(str);
                        strStatus  = jsoObject.getString("status");
                        strActive_status = jsoObject.getString("active_status");
                        strActive_msg = jsoObject.getString("active_message");
                        if(strStatus.equals("1")){
                           // System.exit(0);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(context,Home.class);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
                            context.startActivity(intent);
                            createNotification(context);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //      _progressDialog.dismiss();
                    if (error.getClass().equals(TimeoutError.class)) {
                        CallbackSnakebarModel.getInstance().SnakebarMessage(context, "It took longer than expected to get the response from Server.",
                                MessageConstant.toast_warning);
                    }else {
                        CallbackSnakebarModel.getInstance().SnakebarMessage(context, "Server Respond Error! Try Again Later",
                                MessageConstant.toast_warning);
                    }      }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("hawker_code", hawker_code);
            params.put("longitude", location_update.LONGITUDE);
            params.put("latitude", location_update.LATTITUDE);
            params.put("duty_status", sStatus);
            params.put("notification_id",SharedPrefrence_Login.getPnotification_id());
            return params;
        }
    };
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQue(stringRequest);

}
```

}

Comment: If your app is crashing due to ANR you should have a stacktrace and other errors in the logcat. Please edit your question and copy those into the question.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the correct architecture. In general, a `BroadcastReceiver` isn't designed to perform a lot of work and it definitely isn't designed to perform asynchronous operations (like network I/O with callbacks). You cannot perform network I/O on the main (UI) thread, and a `BroadcastReceiver`s lifetime is limited so that you cannot perform asynchronous operations with callbacks either.

The correct architecture is to use your `BroadcastReceiver` simply to start a `Service` which will run in the background. The `Service` should then perform the network I/O and show any necessary `Notification`s.

Note that due to tighter restrictions on background processing, background `Service`s are no longer allowed to launch an `Activity`. This is to prevent the user from being interrupted by some random background processing. The proper (user-friendly) approach is for the background `Service` to simply show a `Notification`, informing the user that his attention is needed. The user can then launch the `Activity` (by clicking on the `Notification) when he wants to look at the information.